# PHP Warning - Illegal string offset

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

So I don't understand why this is not working. I'm using Wordpress and a plugin called ACF to populate some data. I'm looping through my repeater field to spit out the data like so:

```
<?php

    $links = get_field('footer_links');  // spits out the array

    if($links) {
        foreach ( $links as $link ) {
            $logo = $link['logo'];
            $link = $link['link'];
            $text = $link['text'];

            echo '<div class="link">';
            echo '  <a href="'.$link.'"><img src="'.$logo.'" /><p>'.$text.'</p></a>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    // Logo spits out a image path
    // link spits out the URL path
    // text SHOULD just spit out the title, however throws PHP warning

?>
```

For the variable `$text` I am getting a PHP warning.

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'text' in...

Why is it that my other variables -- `$logo`, `$link` do not throw this warning? They are created the same way as the other `$text` variable.

I've tried recreating the entire repeater field and changing the name etc.. with no success.

Here is my print_r($links);

```
Array
(
    [0] Array
        (
            [logo] http://domainname.com/imagepath
            [link] http://.....
            [text] Text1
        )

    [1] Array
        (
            [logo] http://domainname.com/imagepath
            [link] http://.....
            [text] Text2
        )

    [2] Array
        (
            [logo] http://domainname.com/imagepath
            [link] http://.....
            [text] Text3
        )

)
```

Comment: Lame hack: `if(!isset($link['text'])) { $link['text'] = ''; }`

Comment: So what does `print_r($links)` or `print_r($link)` inside the loop give you?

Comment: @Scott That's not the question. The question is why it's throwing that error.

Comment: Try `$k = array_keys($link); var_dump($link);` to see if $link['text'] is defined for each loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error is thrown here:

```
$link['text'];
```

Array `$link` is lacking index `['text']`. It's because you are overwriting the array variable here:

```
$link = $link['link'];
```

Change that to:

```
$href = $link['link'];
```

And you're gold.

Comment: @Romes +1 You are overwriting the `$link` array variable. Rename `$link = $link['link']` to `$href = $link['link']`.

Comment: Ha! Thank you @CodeAngry for explaining. I'm not upvoting the answer itself because it doesn't completely answer OP's question as to **why** his code didn't work. EDIT: Thanks for editing. +1 now

Comment: Wow, I'm pretty dumb I didn't even see that! Thanks so much.

Comment: @sjagr It does fix the problem. Any PHP coder should be able to figure out the issue from the solution.

Comment: Yeah right, sorry for not explaining, thought it was obvious enough.

Comment: @Romes: Nah, you're not dumb for making a mistake.

Comment: Plus, that's the kind of mistakes you'll have a tough time debugging, it's good to show anyone else your code in these moments ;-)

Comment: @CodeAngry Unfortunately I still haven't had my coffee and had to spend a moment figuring it out ;)

Comment: @sjagr Thanks for teaching me again I take too many things for granted after 10 years of PHP. :)

Comment: Thanks guys, all well said. It was a tuff one to debug but thanks for catching it. I changed `$link` to `$url` as my fix. It just made since to name the variable "Link" because it was indeed a link. :)